# Handling escape character (\) in Neo4j Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

Is there any way to ingest data with backslash (\) character into Neo4j without replacing it with double backslash (\\)

Comment: Is it OK to change your input string some other way, or do you want to avoid changing it in any way?

Answer (score 0):

The `\` is the escape character in Neo4j, so if you want use it as a character you need to escape it by double it, ie `\\`.

There is no way to avoid this...

But, it can be totally transparent for you if you use a parameterized query : Neo4j's driver will escape all specific characters of yours parameters